# preferred way to modify attributes

Tags: python, oop, methods, helper

I'm using a helper method in my class to modify an attribute, and can see several ways to do this.  Are any of the following `helper` and associated `methods` preferred or avoided for good reason?

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def _x_helper1(self):
        self.x += self.y

    def method1(self):
        # some other code...
        self._x_helper1()

    def _x_helper2(self, y):
        # some other code...
        self.x += y

    def method2(self):
        # some other code...
        self._x_helper2(self.y)

    def _x_helper3(self, y):
        # some other code...
        return y

    def method3(self):
        # some other code...
        self.x += self._x_helper3(self.y)
```

Comment: Without proper context, there's no way of comparing these. How you split your code into methods depends on readability, testability, and reduction of duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is way too abstract.

Nothing is wrong with just adding `obj.x + obj.y`. If you need to mutate object's state, and you mutate based on attributes only, use

```
def mutate(self):
    self.x += self.y
```